# How to select C compiler when compiling a cgo binary with bazel?

Tags: go, bazel, cgo

I have a Go binary that I'm trying to build with bazel using the [go_binary rule](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/docs/go/core/rules.md#go_binary). The output is a c-archive that is meant to be consumed on iOS. I would like set the C compiler to be the output of `xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find clang`. However, it doesn't look like there is a way to change the C compiler or set an environment variable like `CC` in the `go_binary` rule. Is there a way to change the C compiler?